# PMU Cache Events on Intel i7 (Ivy Bridge)

Tags: linux, performance, x86-64, oprofile

I'm using Oprofile to profile some benchmarks, I'm looking specifically for caching issues. I'm with the Intel SDM Volume 3 (from March 2013) as my guide for choosing what events to monitor... however it's being a pain..

The computer I'm doing the experiments is a i7 3630QM (that is, Ivy Bridge), so in the manual I'm looking in tables 19-1 and 19-5, the problem is: which events should I use to measure L1{D,I} cache events? What about L3 (LLC)? Sincerely, the events description of table 19-5 are more vague than the habitual.

My system is Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

Use `perf list` to get a list of the supported events and their `perf` names. You'll see events like `L1-dcache-loads` and `LLC-load-misses` that you can use.

FYI, it usually takes a while for a new microarchitecture to make it into `perf` in the kernel, and another while for that kernel version to make it into distributions, so it might happen that your kernel isn't *Ivy Bridge* aware if you're using, say, the default kernel with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll edit my question. Currently I'm using only Oprofile. I guess they use the same event list and interface (perf_events). But I didn't remember seeing anything like L1-d or LLC in ophelp output.

Comment: “Look at oprofile. F*ck me, what a horrid piece of crap.” — Linus Torvalds.

Comment: Ask Linus :)  I think it was in the context of a suggestion to take the userland `perf` tools out of the kernel source, which he opposed using `oprofile` as a counter example because its userland tools and kernel module had gotten very out-of-sync and turned into a giant mess.